# Hot reload for AssemblyLoadContext?

Tags: .net, hot-reload, assemblyloadcontext

Can I somehow utilize the same mechanism as the debug-time hot reload feature is, for my own assemblies loaded in an AssemblyLoadContext at runtime outside of a debugging session?

In my program I runtime compile (collectible) assemblies and invoke code in them via a web api. When changes are made to the code I rebuild and replace the assembly. It would be nice if I could utilize the same mechanism that "hot reload" use, which I assume in not just rebuilding/reloading the entire assembly but change assemblies in memory on a more granular level?